# Trouble solving recursive function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have trouble solving a (what looks like very easy) recursive function

$a_0 = 0 \\ a_n = 2a_{n-1}+3$

Hints/Techniques for how to solve this would be highly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Just try to go backwards.
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+3=2\left(2a_{n-2}+3\right)+3=\dots$$
till the last termin $a_0$

Comment: For your work: $$a_n=-3+3\cdot 2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

- Write out the first few terms.
- Notice that they're divisible by $3$.
- Divide them by $3$.
- Recognise the resulting sequence.
- Prove your formula by induction.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways could be as follows. Write down the formula for $n$-th and $n+1$-th terms. We want to translate the non-homogenous recurrence relation into a homogenous one. This means we want to get rid of the $3$ from the recurrence.
$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 3\\
a_{n+1} = 2a_{n} + 3
$$

Subtract both equalities:
$$
a_n - a_{n+1} = 2a_{n-1} + 3 - (2a_{n} + 3) \\
-a_{n+1} = 2a_{n-1} - 2a_n  - a_n \\
a_{n+1} = 3a_n - 2a_{n-1} \\
a_{n+1} - 3a_n + 2a_{n-1} = 0
$$

Now writing down a characteristic equation for this you may obtain:
$$
\lambda^2 - 3\lambda + 2 = 0 \iff \\
(\lambda - 1)(\lambda -2) = 0
$$

Thus your recurrence will be in the form:
$$
a_{n} = C_1\lambda_1^{n} + C_2\lambda_2^{n}
$$

Using initial conditions lets find the coefficients. We're given:
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0 = 0 \\
a_1 = 3
\end{cases}
$$

Now solve a simple linear system:
$$
\begin{cases}
C_1(1)^{0} + C_2(2)^{0} = 0\\
C_1(1)^{1} + C_2(2)^{1} = 3\\
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases}
C_1 + C_2 = 0\\
C_1 + 2C_2 = 3\\
\end{cases} \\
\begin{cases}
C_1 = -3\\
C_2 = 3
\end{cases}
$$

Thus your recurrence is given by:
$$
a_{n} = -3 + 3\cdot2^n
$$

Comment: This is really taking the long road..

Comment: @Did I know, but OP requested for techniques, one of which is solving by characteristic equation

Comment: But what they really need (and which might already be in their notes) is the centering $y=x-c$ around the fixed point $c=ac+b$, which reduces each recursion $x\to ax+b$ with $a\ne1$ into the recursion $y\to ay$.

Comment: @Did Well, I may delete the answer if you think it's not worth it

Comment: A more productive option would be to rewrite it carefully along the line I indicated. One could also do nothing and wait for this PSQ to be closed...

Comment: @Did would rather stick to the second option

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

A small trick for such kind of recurrence relation $$a_n=2a_{n-1}+3$$
Let $a_n=b_n+k$ and replace
$$b_n+k=2b_{n-1}+2k+3\implies b_n=2b_{n-1}+k+3$$ If you choose $k+3=0$, what do you find ?